# Why is a CSS file not changing the colors of HTML tags on Django project?

Tags: html, css, django

I've been working on adding css styles to my django web project, but I noticed something odd I can't understand.

My page is succesfully adding or removing a gif when I add it or remove it in my css file, but the color of my labels, for instance, doesn't change. This is my simple css file that works this way:

```
li a {
    color: green;
}
body {
    background: white url("images/background.gif") no-repeat;
}
```

When in my browser, I can see if I delete the second statement, the gif no longer appears, but whether I delete or not the first one, all text is still black. I also tried this:

```
h1 a, h2 a {
     color: #C25100;
}
```

But it works the same, it doesn't change any text, and the document has many different tags, and none is affected.

I include the css in my html file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'app_name/style.css' %}">
```

When I first figured it out, I had bootstrap linked too, but I removed it and it changed nothing.

Comment: What does it say in the console? Is it showing a ```404``` for the css file or ```302```?

Comment: Neither, everything "seems" to be working fine, just the color of the tags isn't changed (I don't know if something else isn't working, for now it seems to be just the colors not changing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color isn't changing because `h1 a` means `a` inside `h1`. I guess you should change that to `h1, a` this means h1 and `a`. [Read more here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had the same problem, turns out that I didn't close one of curly braces in .css file

Comment: this should be comment

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31810927)

Comment: Yes, sorry guys, forgot that such thing as comments exists